# How to run python source file and display source code and output

Tags: python

[Added] **Background**: I am trying to make a script to preprocess markdown files containing examples in various languages (R, Stata, and python for now). For each markdown file, my script extracts the code blocks and save the code blocks to files, say "temp.R", "temp.do", and "temp.py".

When I source temp.R (R) and temp.do (Stata), I get log files containing both inputs and outputs, line by line. The commands are `R CMD BATCH -q temp.R` and `stata-mp -q -b temp.do`. I would like similar outputs for python.

When I source temp.py, I see only the outputs. I want to have a "log" file like what I would see if I copy and paste the source into a python interactive session, without worrying about incomplete lines.

**Question:** My "temp.py" file contains:

```py
1+1
if True:
    print('True')

msg = "Hello, world!"
print(msg)
```

I would like to get:

```
>>> 1+1
2
>>> if True:
...     print('True')
...
True
>>> msg = "Hello, world!"
>>> print(msg)
Hello, world!
```

by `some_command temp.py` like what I would see if the source lines are typed in a python interactive session. Is it possible? I've tried `cat temp.py | python` and `python < temp.py` in no avail. The actual python source files can be large and complicated.

Comment: I cannot think of one possible use for this. What is the bigger goal?

Comment: Do you just want to print the original source code, or are you trying to simulate line-by-line execution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How print every line of a python script as its being executed (including the console)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686761/how-print-every-line-of-a-python-script-as-its-being-executed-including-the-con)

Comment: @Brian61354270 I just want the printed output. What I want is ">>> source line" follows by "output" for every line just like when the source codes are manually typed in the python shell.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Thanks for the link. Now I see the relevance. (I don't know why I thought it was not when I read it yesterday.) I wonder if there is a simple way to do it without writing a script to run the script. I worry about possible unfinished lines  if I have the file executed line by line.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with a simple bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

cat $1 && python $1
```

Then call it like this:

```bash
./my_script.sh main.py
```

And it will echo the source code and then execute it.